# Duplicate Apps on Android iOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-play, app-store

I have an app made on React Native but I was required by client to build the same app on Android and iOS but with different name, splashscreen, icons, internal colors, database but with same functionalities and design.

**So as example**, today I have a Food App for Client A.

- Food App -> Client A (nameA, splashcreenA, iconsA, green color, databaseA)
- Food App -> Client B (nameB, splashcreenB, iconsB, red color, databaseB)
- Food App -> Client C (nameC, splashcreenC, iconsC, yellow color, databaseC)
- ...n apps

I am asking here because I am still waiting for Apple official answer to this question. Google could not answer because directly they only answer Google Play apps issues.

The question is; is there any problem by submitting the same apps but with different name, icons, splash, colors and database, but with same functionalities.

Comment: AFAIK - it is just fine (for google)

Comment: @julio you were able to duplicate the app in App Store? any problem with that?

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be a problem, and less if the developer / enterprise who uploaded the app is the same to both apps.

Comment: The only problem comes when someone report your app because is a copy of him app. In this case won't happen because you won't report your self xD

Answer (score 1):

Here are the relevant section from the apple store review guidelines.

[copycats](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#copycats)

[spam](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#spam)

I know of an app that was rejected due to being a spam app.  The case was very similar to your situation i.e multiple similar apps with different branding in the same developer account.  In that case the situation was solved by publishing in different developer accounts for each app.

Comment: Copycats talks about "property infringement claim", and it's an app created by same company so there should be no problem I believe.

Answer (score 1):

On Android the functionnality is called "Product Flavors" :

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

I don't know how it work with react native but with Android Studio you just have to configure the two apps and then you have two folders into your your project.

- In the first on you can store whatever you want
- In the second one all the file will **override** the file with the same name in the first folder

That mean you can set anothers icons, color but also modify a class to have acomportment a bit different.

There is no problem by submitting the same apps on the Play Store.

I have not worked on this functionnality on iOS (but it exist) so I don't know what is it's name. But the company I have worked for had no problem for submitting two same apps on the store.

I think there is no problem is the 2 apps have not the same goal or doesn't target the same audience.

Answer (score 0):

All Google Play Policy questions are usually best answered by looking at the [Google Play Developer Policy Center](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/). The most relevant answer about your case seems to be the ["Wizard Spam" answer](https://play.google.com/about/spam-min-functionality/spam/wizard/). I'd read that carefully. It seems from the answer you will want to create a different developer account for each client.